# Why would breakpoints in VS2008 stop working?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have a c# asp.net web app. Breakpoints in the database layer are no longer stopping execution but the breakpoints in the UI layer are still working okay. Can anyone hazard a guess why this might be happening?

I've checked all the usual suspects (Debug build is on for all projects) and recompiled all projects in solution...

Answer (score 1):

I would ensure that the UI layer is referencing the appropriate 'debug' .dll's. I'd also consider pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> (`Modules View`) when you're debugging to see if symbols are loaded for your BLL and DAL `.dlls`. If not then Visual Studio is unable to find `.PDBs` for that file.
Are debug files `.PDBs` in the same directory as the `.dlls` that are being referenced from the Modules window?

Answer (score 1):

- Attach the debugger to ASP.NET process and click on the modules window. Ensure that debugging symbols are loaded for the assemblies you want to debug.
- Make sure the UI is referencing the debug assemblies, not release assemblies.
- Make sure the .PDB files are in the /bin/debug/ directory
- Make sure you rebuild the entire solution before attaching the debugger.
- If the data tier is in a seperate solution, add the project to the UI SLN (You don't need to add a reference, those should already be established or your code wouldn't compile), so that the debugger can pull up the full code.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the responses and ideas guys - I had already tried all of those or variations of them.

I think that it must be a very subtle VS bug. A colleague suggested I make the function that I was trying to break on public (previously "undefined" so was implicitly private) and try again. I did this and the breakpoint started to get hit. I then removed the public keyword and the breakpoint continued to be hit. No idea why this solved it but it did.

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1):

A couple of suggestions.
The first one is to check the status of the breakpoint in the source line. Is it a solid red ball? If not, it generally indicates that the file in question isn't the one used for the build.
Secondly - have a look at the modules view and see what module and symbols have been loaded. You may find it's not what you expect.

As for why - I've no idea!

Nick

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting your bin directories before recompiling?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and kept thinking "what did I change in web.config" to potentially do this?

```
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
```

That was not allowing breakpoints to work for me.